# IE8 & CSS for single item unordered list

Tags: css, internet-explorer

CSS illiterate here. I need to display a list of notes in a page, the problem is that when there is a single note to display I have to hide the bullets and make it seem like a regular label. Using Jquery Im adding a css class to the ul when there's only 1 `<li>` and the results are quite good in chrome/firefox (the table border is displayed here just to show how the table is set up).

Here is a screenshot of chrome and firefox showing the `<ul>` with and without the style applied:

[image]

However in IE8 (dont know other versions) the `<ul>` is not aligned to.. anything really:

[image]

The style Im applying to the `<ul>` is

```
ul.hidestyle {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

I tried using diferent options for the *display* property but nothing seemed to cause any effect. Any help will be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="ctl00_Notes">
  <table cellpadding="2">
    <tr> 
      <td>
        <img id="ctl00_cph_WarningImage" src="../Images/orange_flag.PNG" style="border-width:0px;"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul id="NotesList">
          <li>bla bla bla.</li>
          <li>something else.</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your actual html showing the ul and li with data.

Comment: I've added the HTML, you can remove/update the comment.

Comment: @Ed did you solve the problem? If so - let us know in case somebody else has the same problem in future!

Comment: I ended up applying a style to the ul so it has fixed margins. I used
`ul.NoteList
{
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}`
Im not sure if its pretty but every browser seems to understand that correctly

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN age on list-style-type certainly indicates that none is a valid option:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I don't have IE8 to test with, but I've seen other people use both "list-style-type" and also "list-style-image" of none... and seen them put it both on the ul and on the li eg:

```
ul.hidestyle {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  padding: 2px;
}
ul.hidestyle li {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}
```

It might not work but... worth a try?